# MassTransit In-Memory Outbox in Saga

Tags: masstransit

We did some load tests on a Saga with a In-Memory outbox. During those tests we simulated different types of failures: application restarts, infrastructure restart, message broker restart etc.

We noticed, that some saga instances did not finish and we had a bunch of errors:
Automatonymous.NotAcceptedStateMachineException: ... {SomeEvent}: Not accepted in state {SomeState}

After some debuging we isolated the problem. I'll try to describe it using this sample code:

```csharp
public class OrderStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<Order>
{
    public OrderStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        During(Initial, 
            When(Create).TransitionTo(New));

        During(New,
            When(AddItem)
                .Then(x => x.Instance.Items.Add(x.Data.Name)),

            When(Submit)
                .ThenAsync(async x =>
                {
                    // do something
                    await x.Publish(new SendEmail {Text = $"Order submitted. {x.Instance.Summary}"});
                })
                .TransitionTo(Submitted));

        During(Submitted,
            When(Accept)
                .ThenAsync(async x =>
                {
                    // do something
                    await x.Publish(new SendEmail {Text = $"Order accepted. {x.Instance.Summary}"});
                })
                .Finalize());

        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }

    public State New { get; private set; }
    public State Submitted { get; private set; }

    public Event<Create> Create { get; private set; }
    public Event<AddItem> AddItem { get; private set; }
    public Event<Submit> Submit { get; private set; }
    public Event<Accept> Accept { get; private set; }
}

public class Order : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string CurrentState { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public string Summary => $"Items: {string.Join(", ", Items)}";
}

public class Create : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class AddItem : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Submit : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class Accept : CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
}

public class SendEmail
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This is what happens:

1. During **Order** in state **New**, we handle **Submit** event, do some
   changes in order, publish **SendEmail** event and transition to
   **Submitted** state.
2. **Order** state is successfully persisted to DB
3. Application crashes (i.e force restart) before it sends the message
   outbox.
4. Application is restarted, **Submit** is delivered the second time, **Order** is in state **Submitted** and we get an Exception Automatonymous.NotAcceptedStateMachineException: ... **Submit**: Not accepted in state **Submitted**

What if this happens in state **Submitted** during **Accept** event handling? My assumption:

1. During **Order** in state **Submitted**, we handle **Accept** event, do some
   changes in order, publish **SendEmail** event and Finalize **Order**
2. **Order** state is removed form DB, because it's finalized and configured to CompletedWhenFinalized
3. Application crashes (i.e force restart) before it sends the message
   outbox.
4. Application is restarted, **Accept** is delivered the second time, **Order** is no longer in DB, we lost all information about it... what happens now?

What is a best solution to handle situations like this? I've read Chris's great [article](https://masstransit-project.com/2020/02/08/in-memory-outbox/) about In-Memory Outbox, but don't understand how can the message be handled during redelivery when Saga is in a state where it no longer handles that message. Of course we can handle the redelivered event in the next state with some tricky logic, but it seems pretty cumbersome. Our Saga is much more complex then the provided sample.

Maybe a transaction which commits after all messages from outbox have been sent, would be a solution? Can the [Transaction Outbox](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/transactions.html#transaction-outbox) be somehow configured with a Saga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've read the article on using the outbox, and you realize that you need to add a handler for `Submit` to the `Submitted` state, that's really the answer. However, unlike the original handler which updated the saga state and was persisted, you only need to regenerate the events that were sent/published. That handles the first part of the problem, *Submitted*.

The second part is a different answer, and it is pretty simple actually. You don't finalize the order in Accept. You create an additional state, *Accepted*, that the order transitions to after being accepted. And you remove the order instances after a period of time (a week, a month, whatever). That way, when the Accept message is delivered to the Accepted instance, you can regenerate the events that were published.

Now, you could use Quartz to schedule a future message to finalize the saga, which doesn't do any business logic, but only removes the saga instance. And you could set up an Initially(When(RemoveOrder).Ignore()) handler that would discard the remove order message if the saga doesn't exist. And that makes it automatic. But in past systems we've just archived a date range partition of the file group (in SQL server) or deleted the older records after 30 or 90 days or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is clear now. The second case is actually not an issue for us. We never planned to automatically complete finalized sessions. We have an external mechanism which archives old records and is executed directly on the database.

Comment: On this @ChrisPatterson  I have tried using the in memory test harness to test the republication  but it seems that the final state (either a custom state or using the built in final state itself)  is not being recognised. My test DOESNT create an error but simply sends in another message (I am using mediator not Mass Transit based messaging ) which it seems wouldnt be unreasonable in thinking that mimics a message into the statemachine being reprocessed regardless of an error. Have you any examples of this working in a test?

Comment: @brumScouse asking a question in a comment of an answer is not how you should approach the question you have about using mediator with a saga. Mediator is not a transport, so it does not behavior even closely to a transport.

Comment: I will have to refer to the stack overflow guidelines, I guess I was trying to short circuit and the question is related I felt  
I understand the mediator is not a transport, absolutely.  I am using a mediator with a number of consumers and a state machine. I am firing in events I handle and created  from the transport (AWS SQS in this case - and in the tests, from within a fixture sans transport) .  My question is firmly around exercising the last state, with the outbox "turned on" using the TestHarness.  I think it is still a valid question.  Perhaps I can create a specific question